# difference between two date time fields in days

Tags: formula, formula-field, process-builder, datetime

I have a datetime field `field1` which i am populating using `NOW()` formula.
At some point later i want to know the difference between `NOW()` and `field1` in number of days.

I tried `NOW()-field1` and `DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - DATETIMEVALUE(field1)`, but it does not seem to be correct.

I am storing this result in a number field which can store 6 decimal places. But when i multiply the value by 60*24, it does not return correct result.
If the difference is 12 hours between `NOW` and `field1`, I want the field to have .5 as value. If the difference is 6 hours, it should have .25

Comment: `NOW() - DateTime_Field__c` works very well for me. Why do you mean it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is right, but you should use only 2 decimal places in your formula number field.

I have tested the following:

- `NOW()` field (DateTime formula)
- DateTime field
- Difference field with formula `NOW()- ut__Datetime__c` (number formula, 2 decimal places)

Works well:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
Now()-Field1__c - FLOOR(Now()-Field1__c)
```

For more info go to the [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006172&language=en_US)

Answer (score 2):

If you use it in Apex, this works:

```
(f2.getTime() - f1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

first you calculate difference in milliseconds between datetimes, then get number of days from it.